# How do I return a specific exit code from NANT?

Tags: nant

I have a nant script and I see that even if my exec fails, the exit code of NANT is 0 anyway. How do I change NANT exit code?

Answer (score 1):

The [exec task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html) has an attribute called "resultproperty", which is there to get the exit code.

Answer (score 1):

#### Returning a Specific Exit Code from NANT

If the build succeeds NANT will exit with code 0, if the build fails NANT with code 1 and you can use `<fail>` to force this. NANT gives no other way of controlling the exit code however you could hack it:

```
<script language="C#">
    <code>
        <![CDATA[
        public static void ScriptMain(Project project) 
        { 
            System.Environment.Exit(3);
        }
        ]]>
    </code>
</script>
```

This will end nant immediately, so perhaps you might want to create a target to be run at the very end by putting it into *nant.onsuccess*.

#### Why NANT Exit Code is 0 when `<exec>` Failed?

`<exec>` fails when the command exits with anything but 0. Normally this causes the whole build to fail in consequence and NANT to exit with code 1, with two exceptions (see 2 and 3). This gives us three possible explanations:

1. Your *command* fails but exits with 0 anyway (this is a relatively common behavior). Set the `resultproperty` attribute and check the property.
2. `failonerror="False"` attribute has been set on `<exec>` or on a higher level (`<nant>` or `<call>`). Check the NANT output to see in which order targets are being called or search for `failonerror=`.
3. The `<exec>` is executed as part of target started via the *nant.onsuccess* resp. *nant.onfailure* property hook. Check if and where by searching for `nant.on`.

To say anything more a sample NANT script or perhaps a log file would be useful.